# How to parse complex url encoded parameters into JSON

Tags: .net, json.net

Using .net, I'd like to take get request from the client where a complex json object is url encoded using jquery

```
var opts = {"BillingSession":{"InvoiceDate":"2018-04-18T00:00:00.000", "testKey": "testVal"}, "invoices": ["one", "two"], "SessionDiary": "diarynum"}
$.get("url", obj)
```

results in url

```
/url?BillingSession%5BInvoiceDate%5D=2018-04-18T00%3A00%3A00.000&BillingSession%5BtestKey%5D=testVal&invoices%5B%5D=one&invoices%5B%5D=two&SessionDiary=diarynum
```

How can I parse this with JSON.NET? HttpUtility.ParseQueryString only returns simple key & values; e.g.

```
"billingSession[testKey]" = "testVal"
```

I would like to get a proper JObject from the url string.

Answer (score 0):

---

Have you tried NewtonSoft Json.Net?

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Yes, currently actively use it to decode json coming in via POST body. But, I've not been able to discern how to similarly decode urlcoded content.

Comment: What about using HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode after parsing?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6196h3wt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: UrlDecode will decode the url string. However, it doesn't help parsing that to JSON.